# Filter pandas dataframe by quantile based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble applying some filter to my dataset, can't get my head around on how to do it. I have a dataframe that consist of 7 columns. One column, `participant_id` that identifies a participant (numerical value unique to each participant), a second column that indicates to which group each partipant belongs to (`group`), a third column called `trial` that identifies the trial (each participant performs multiple trials of a task) and four columns `var 1`, `var 2`, `var 3`, `var 4` (a numerical value corresponding to four variables recorded of each trial). There are participants with 100+ trials, and participants with around 50 trials.

Short example:

```py
       participant_id        group         trial       var1        var2       var3        var4        
         189                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562  
         189                   A             2      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         189                   A             3      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         189                   A             4      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         345                   B             1         NaN       0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         345                   B            378     -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             2      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         432                   B            517     -0.231046    0.245615     NaN      -0.593562
         432                   B             2      -0.231046    0.245615     NaN      -0.593562
         432                   B            333     -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
```

Example for 4 participants. Note that the trial number is not unique, as two different participants can have a trial '1', and the same participant also can have multiple trial '1'. (Don't mind that the value of the var columns is the same for every row, in the real dataset that's not the case). The real dataset is 10000 rows.

What I need to do is to keep the top n quantile trials of each unique participant based on the value of
`var1`. I was thinking of using the pandas .quantile(n) function, but I don't know how to tell it that it should analyze each participant separately, and not the whole row to get the quantile.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `apply()` on a group is passed a Dataframe of each group
- have provided example using `lambda` as well as stand alone function
- sample data as noted does not have any feature to demonstrate it's function

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""       participant_id        group         trial       var1        var2       var3        var4        
         189                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562  
         189                   A             2      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         189                   A             3      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         189                   A             4      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         345                   B             1         NaN       0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         345                   B            378     -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             1      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         227                   A             2      -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
         432                   B            517     -0.231046    0.245615     NaN      -0.593562
         432                   B             2      -0.231046    0.245615     NaN      -0.593562
         432                   B            333     -0.231046    0.245615  -0.581238   -0.593562
"""), sep="\s+")

def f(d):
    return d.quantile()

df.groupby("participant_id", as_index=False).apply(f)
df.groupby("participant_id", as_index=False).apply(lambda d: d.quantile())
```

#### updated

- question was how to utilise pandas quantile capabilities within groups, answered by first part
- this specifically shows how to use this approach to filter to rows within quantiles
- have generated a random dataset that is same shape for demonstration purposes

```
# generate a useful dataset to analyse...
s = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"participant_id":np.random.choice([189,227,345,432],s),
             "trial":np.random.randint(1,6,s),
             "group":np.random.choice(["A","B"],s),
              "var1":np.random.rand(s),
              "var2":np.random.rand(s),
              "var3":np.random.rand(s),
              "var4":np.random.rand(s),
             })

# split into 10 quantile bins and take 0th bin
# split into 10 quantile bins and take 0th bin
df.groupby("participant_id").apply(
    lambda d: d.loc[pd.qcut(d.var1, q=10, retbins=False, labels=False).le(0)]).droplevel(0)
```

|  | participant_id | trial | group | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 189 | 3 | A | 0.0273875 | 0.87134 | 0.555792 | 0.67094 |
| 85 | 189 | 1 | A | 0.0106758 | 0.352578 | 0.481009 | 0.910989 |
| 91 | 189 | 4 | A | 0.00835706 | 0.644102 | 0.990459 | 0.816669 |
| 4 | 227 | 5 | B | 0.10132 | 0.870446 | 0.389972 | 0.313782 |
| 71 | 227 | 4 | B | 0.0221867 | 0.17566 | 0.659024 | 0.910838 |
| 74 | 227 | 1 | A | 0.0762526 | 0.458995 | 0.492384 | 0.556408 |
| 28 | 345 | 5 | A | 0.130674 | 0.0336628 | 0.0429884 | 0.799307 |
| 82 | 345 | 1 | B | 0.234522 | 0.371108 | 0.451911 | 0.54528 |
| 93 | 345 | 4 | B | 0.272915 | 0.594262 | 0.392285 | 0.56374 |
| 16 | 432 | 2 | B | 0.0403964 | 0.880132 | 0.45438 | 0.0466626 |
| 18 | 432 | 5 | A | 0.0884496 | 0.304541 | 0.969059 | 0.949315 |
| 22 | 432 | 2 | B | 0.115796 | 0.0371306 | 0.631284 | 0.537881 |
| 55 | 432 | 2 | B | 0.102859 | 0.0416843 | 0.761466 | 0.56438 |

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself correctly (or I'm doing something wrong), but if I'm not mistaken those methods return the quantile value, what I want is all the values that are over that value

Comment: have updated answer - I understood your question to be how to use these types of capabilities in groups of data.  have gone one step further to show how to use to filter data to be within quantiles.  Clearly you can adjust bins and which bins you want